# how to know which one matching when using WHERE and OR term

Tags: sql

I have a sql code like below:

```
SELECT user_name, user_e_mail, user_phone 
    FROM users 
WHERE user_name=:user_name 
OR user_e_mail=:email 
OR user_phone=:phone
```

Normally, I'm trying to get 0 or 1(if there is match or not). But  I don't want to create more sql query. Shortly, my question is how to know which one matching (name,mail or phone)?

I hope I could tell what the my problem is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard SQL syntax for this would return a separate flag for each condition:

```
SELECT user_name, user_e_mail, user_phone,
       (case when user_name = :user_name then 1 else 0 end) as MatchesName,
       (case when user_e_mail = :user_e_mail then 1 else 0 end) as MatchesEmail,
       (case when user_phone = :user_phone then 1 else 0 end) as MatchesPhone
FROM users 
WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_e_mail=:email OR user_phone=:phone;
```

If you just want to know the first one that matches:

```
SELECT user_name, user_e_mail, user_phone,
       (case when user_name = :user_name then 'Name'
             when user_e_mail = :user_e_mail then 'Email'
             when user_phone = :user_phone then 'Phone'
        end) as which
FROM users 
WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_e_mail=:email OR user_phone=:phone;
```

Comment: +1 because I do like the second approach too--that is sometimes what you're looking for, a description of the changed field and often the first is enough.

Comment: Array ( [which] => Name [0] => Name ) returns. Why it isn't just array([which] => Name) ??

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be like this:

```
SELECT user_name, user_e_mail, user_phone,
    :user_name = user_name AS user_name_matches,
    :email = user_e_mail AS email_matches,
    :phone = user_phone AS phone_matches
FROM users 
WHERE user_name=:user_name 
OR user_e_mail=:email 
OR user_phone=:phone
```

and here's a [SQL Fiddle that proves it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/967a6f/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Secondly the SQL Query optimiser may alter the order of your WHERE clause based on your table statistics so this problem can only be solved by using nested WHERE checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name, user_e_mail, user_phone,
   CASE WHEN :user_name = user_name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS user_name_matches,
   CASE WHEN :email = user_e_mail THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS email_matches,
   CASE WHEN :phone = user_phone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS phone_matches
FROM users 
WHERE user_name=:user_name 
   OR user_e_mail=:email 
   OR user_phone=:phone
```